# GCS upload is realy slow from GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have setup a simple python project on GAE, the user picks a file and it uploads into Google Cloud Storage. This all works fine, but I am getting an upload time of 10-11 seconds when I am uploading a 100kb file. How can I reduce this?

Extra info:
I have a 100Mbis upload speed and the result is the same with a 4kb image, the latency of the first post id about 6 seconds[image]

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2

    from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

    class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name='bucket_name')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
            name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

    class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
      def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

    class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
      def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                                   ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                                   ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                                  debug=True)
```

Comment: If you do not upload large files, you can try to use cgi.file storage to upload the file. See gcs_upload.py here: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133

Comment: the files uploaded by the users will e about 1mb, any reason why this should be faster using this script?

Comment: I do not understand why you small upload takes 11 seconds. With the script I provided the form upload (submit) is handeld by your own handler. No blob upload handler involved to find out where your problem is.

Comment: Awsome, I have tryied the script but when i do i get     gcs_file_name = gcs_data.gcs_write_blob(dyn, field_storage.file.read())
NameError: global name 'field_storage' is not defined any ide?

Comment: So yes this is so much faster! Thanks!
But i don't like that fact that I have to put more load on the GAE instance would be nice to find out what the bottleneck is

Comment: Change the line in: gcs_file_name = gcs_data.gcs_write_blob(dyn, file_data)

Comment: Is this latency still occurring, OP? Did you notice the speed returned to a more expected speed after a while?